# How to prevent WaaSMedicAgent from modifying a specific registry key/value without disabling critical services?

Tags: windows, windows-update

I've made a few modifications to registry keys related to Windows Update (specifically but not limited to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DoSvc` value `ImagePath`) and I want to preserve those changes. However, the infamous WaaSMedicAgent eventually reverts them back to default values. How do I stop this from happening while

- Keeping Windows Update *enabled*
- Keeping WaaSMedicAgent *enabled*

I still want these system services to work, I just want them to do so with my custom configuration

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Some system components can be restricted by setting appropriate permissions on the registry key.

Comment: I've changed ownership of the keys from `SYSTEM` to my own user, then denied write permissions to `SYSTEM` and `TrustedInstaller`, but `WaaSMedicAgent` just takes ownership back since it runs as `SYSTEM`. Another idea (but I don't know if it's possible or how to do it) is to configure Windows Defender or AppLocker to protect a specific key. Right now, I'm trying to figure out if I can remove some security tokens from WaaSMedicAgent to prevent it from taking ownership or changing privileges, but that would partially break it's function.